# Hide application from app grid?

Tags: app-drawer

I want my app grid to be minimized to the app I want only. Some apps are built-in by my phone provider and cannot be uninstalled from the phone via `System - Application` menu.

I saw the old phone Samsung Galaxy S that helps us to hide it from app grid but with my new Android phone the Galaxy Nexus, I cannot find it.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the launcher you are using. The stock Samsung Galaxy S4 launcher (TouchWiz) supports it.

[image]

If the stock launcher doesn't have it, you can use [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher). It allows you to hide apps so you don't see them on the app drawer.

[image]

**UPDATE #1:** According to Izzy's comments below, the following launchers also have a similar feature:

- [Apex Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apex-launcher/com.anddoes.launcher)
- [Go Launcher Ex](http://www.appbrain.com/app/go-launcher-ex/com.gau.go.launcherex)
- [ADW Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/adw-launcher/org.adw.launcher)
- [ADW Launcher Ex](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.adwfreak.launcher)

Comment: Same applies for some other Launchers as well, so you have something to select from: e.g. [Apex Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apex-launcher/com.anddoes.launcher) or [Go Launcher Ex](http://www.appbrain.com/app/go-launcher-ex/com.gau.go.launcherex).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks! That's good to know. Added it into the answer.

Comment: You're welcome! I bet there are a lot more, but those 3 are the only ones I'm sure of :) // Edit: [ADW Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/adw-launcher/org.adw.launcher) and [ADW Launcher Ex](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.adwfreak.launcher) also seem to support this (according to their playstore descriptions: *hide unwanted apps*).

Comment: A launcher means I have to use a new homescreen? I don't want it that way since the app drawer/app grid has nothing to do with my homescreen in hiding its items. I really don't want to get it via a launcher app. Is there a app just built to hide app in app grid solely?

Comment: @NamG.VU Added a new paragraph in mu answer - 1st paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom launcher like [ADW](http://adwthings.com/launcher/) to freely arrange icons and add/remove them.

If you want to uninstall apps that your firmware will not let you, use [adb](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).

Comment: Sorry if I accidentally downvoted this answer. I can't seem to upvote agqin unless the answer is edited.

Comment: It is edited ^^ @geffchang

Comment: @Lennart So nice to know that we can uninstall firmware-protecting apps! I'm excited to try that ^^